# Why is my delegate only passing the First member of the Array?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue

I have a view controller where a user can add and delete areas, I currently will add multiple members to the array, and then attempt to pass the data back. It will send the first member and the rest get lost.

I've troubleshot how many areas have at each point, and I've pinpointed it to when the data gets passed back into that View, It only has 1 member.

Here is where the array is declared in the first VC:

```
var areas = [areaProps(x: "New Area", y: "", z: "", a: "", b: "", p1: nil, p2: nil, p3: nil)]
```

Here is where it is saved back:

```
func setArray(obj: [areaProps]) {
    areas = obj
    print("Set Array Sucessfully")
    print(areas.count)// contains the actual amount of objects that were created.
}

    override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent:parent)
    if parent == nil {
        print("Back Button Pressed")
        delegate?.setArray(obj: areaArray)
    }
}
```

And when it is passed back here is how, and showing that it only has 1 member here:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToMainDetails"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! addOverview
        vc.overview = overview
    } else if segue.identifier == "goToServiceArea"{ // this is the segue
        let vc = segue.destination as! areaDetails
        vc.areaArray = areas
        print(" \(areas.count) Areas in Array ") // the array contains only 1 object
    } else {

    }
}
```

Here is the class of the delegate and where it is initialized:

```
  var delegate:AreaDelegate?



protocol AreaDelegate {
    func setArray(obj: [areaProps])
}
```

To also clarify what is going on here, the first object in the array will pass over with its edited properties, however and additional object will not pass. For example if i change the title of the 1st area in the second view, it will pass back and forth with that new title.

Here is my AreaProps Class if it helps

```
      var area : String
    var fix : String
    var surface : String
    var density : String
    var pic1 : UIImage?
    var pic2 : UIImage?
    var pic3 : UIImage?
    var notes : String

override init() {
    area = ""
    fix = ""
    surface = ""
    density = ""
    notes = ""
    pic1 = nil
    pic2 = nil
    pic3 = nil
}
convenience init(x : String, y : String, z : String, a : String, b : String, p1 : UIImage?, p2: UIImage?, p3: UIImage?) {

    self.init()

    let size : CGSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        area = x
        fix = y
        surface = z
        density = a
        notes = b
        pic1 = p1
        pic1 = pic1?.imageResize(sizeChange: size)
        pic2 = p2
        pic2 = pic2?.imageResize(sizeChange: size)
        pic3 = p3
        pic3 = pic3?.imageResize(sizeChange: size)

    }
```

Comment: Can you post more code? In your current code is not the problem I think.

Comment: What is your delegate? Where do you set it? Its hard to understand the corelation between your objects from these snippets - can you edit your question with entire classess?

Comment: Yes what else can i post to clarify>

Comment: @SeanStayn  I have updated the post with more information and class declarations-- hopefully that allows you to understand my issue

Comment: @Losiowaty I have added in where i set the delegate and the protocol to support it as wel

Comment: what is `areaProps()` ??

Comment: This is ust a declarataion of a variable. Since its and optional, its default value is `nil`, which then causes the line `delegate?.setArray(...)` to effectively do nothibg. Where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: @Losiowaty The delegate calls properly as I added in a print statement to confirm, i added in the line where i declare it as a variable.

Comment: @jms i will update to post the class.

Comment: You have added only one object of class into var areas = [areaProps(x: "New Area", y: "", z: "", a: "", b: "", p1: nil, p2: nil, p3: nil)] in this line. if you want more then one element var areas = [areaProps(x: "New Area", y: "", z: "", a: "", b: "", p1: nil, p2: nil, p3: nil),areaProps(x: "New Area", y: "", z: "", a: "", b: "", p1: nil, p2: nil, p3: nil)] you can replace this line with above

Comment: @VishalPatel I append more objects in the other view and then pass it back over, but only the first will update and add

Comment: @VishalPatel I need to figure out how to get the entire array to be set = to the one that was created in the previous view-- instead of just the first item being updated

Comment: @VishalPatel How can i make the array have as many objects as the one i am passing?

Comment: see my last comment. you can do it like that.

Comment: @VishalPatel Yes but that will only allow the first 2 objects in the array to pass over, i need all of them

Comment: It’s depends on you how many objects you added into array. If you add 100 objects into array then 100 objects pass.

Comment: @VishalPatel Thats why this situation is so strange because I want to add an unlimited amount of objects, and then pass them back but the only ones that carry over changed are the ones that were in the array to start when i initialized the array like you suggested